# Is the function $f(x)=x$ on $\{\pm\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

This is really a question of definitions. If a function $f$ is not defined on an open set containing $x$, how do we define the derivative of $f$? Is it sufficient to be locally approximable by linear functions on its points of definition, or do we consider the function not differentiable here? I am interested in defining a function $D:\Bbb R^{\subseteq\Bbb R}\to\Bbb R^{\subseteq\Bbb R}$ such that $x\in\operatorname{dom}D(f)$ and $D(f)(x)=f'(x)$ whenever $f$ is differentiable at $x$. When $f$ has a peculiar domain in the neighborhood of $x$, the exact definition of the limit is confusing me. What is the derivative at an isolated point?

**Edit:** Here is my proposed definition for a derivative, defined as a predicate on possible limits, that makes sense when $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $A$, the domain of $f$, even if $x_0\notin A$:

> $f$ has derivative $L$ at $x_0$ iff for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta$ such that for any $x,y$, $$x,y\in A\cap B(x_0,\delta)\wedge x\ne y\implies\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-L\right|<\varepsilon.$$

This definition actually makes sense even if $x_0$ is an isolated point or an exterior point of $A$, but in these cases $f$ has every number as a derivative (by contrast to when $f$ is genuinely not differentiable in the conventional sense, in which case no number is a derivative). If one adds the proviso "$x_0$ is an interior point of $A\cup\{x_0\}$", one recovers the conventional definition, except that the point $x_0$ is not required to be defined, which allows you to patch over removable singularities.

Comment: There's no problem in defining the derivative relative to a set such that the point of interest is a limit point of the set (and this is a fairly common idea; in fact, Hedrick wrote a fairly thorough paper on this way back in 1907 [*On derivatives over assemblages*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1907-008-03/)), but I'm not aware of anything having been usefully done in the case that the point is isolated from the set.

Comment: @Thomas Even granting its definition on an open set minus the point, I see no reason to require it to be defined at the point itself. It's a limit, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard definition of ''$f$ differentiable at $x_0$" usually includes a requirement that $x_0$ is an interior point of the domain of $f$, but really the limit that defines the derivative makes sense as long as $x_0$ is a point in the domain of $f$ that is also an accumulation point of the domain of $f$.

One issue that could arise is that a function that is not differentiable in the usual sense could have two different derivatives when restricted to two different subdomains. For instance, in your example you define $E = \displaystyle \left\{ \pm \frac 1n : n \in \mathbb N \right\}$. Suppose that $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x) = x$ if $x \in E$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $f|_{E \cup \{0\}}(x) = x$, and $f|_{\mathbb R \setminus E}(x) = 0$. In this case $$\left(f|_{E \cup \{0\}} \right)'(0) = 1,$$ but $$\left( f|_{\mathbb R \setminus E} \right)'(0) = 0.$$

Comment: Is there a reason to require $x_0\in{\rm dom}(f)^\circ$ instead of $x_0\in({\rm dom}(f)\cup\{x_0\})^\circ$? Your multiple-derivatives issue wouldn't appear in this case.