# Limit of minimum and maximum of $f(x)$ on [a,b] as $b\to a$

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose $q$ is a continuous function.

*Is there a rigorous way to prove that:*

$$\lim_{b\to a}\min_{x\in[a,b]}q(x)=q(a)$$
and
$$\lim_{b\to a}\max_{x\in[a,b]}q(x)=q(a)$$

This may be super obvious, but I'm in need of a sanity check. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268965/12952) was a response to a slightly different question but the intuition is the same, check it out

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I don't think I have the same intution sadly. Could you elaborate on that a bit? Are you referring to the fact that $b$ has to approach $a$ from the right?